# Pulling archived tasks when refreshing sandbox

Tags: sandbox-refresh, archive

I noticed that when we refresh our full copy sandbox, the archived task records from production are not brought over to the sandbox. Is it possible to pull the archived tasks during the refresh?

Answer (score 2):

Not copying over the archived activities is documented here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activities_archived.htm&type=5

you can export the archived activities via the dataloader with the export all option from production.  Then insert the activities into the sandbox.  According to this article https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_archive.htm

If you use the API to insert activities that meet the criteria listed below, the activities will be archived during the next run of the archival background process.

Activity archive criteria:

- Events with an ActivityDateTime or ActivityDate value greater than or equal to 365 days old
- Tasks with an IsClosed value of true and an ActivityDate value greater than or equal to 365 days old
- Tasks with an IsClosed value of true, a blank ActivityDate field, and a create date greater than or equal to 365 days ago